# Cannot insert into MS Access database from VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

VB.NET cannot insert data into a MS Access database table.

What can I modify in this code to insert the data into the table?

Error messages:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=loginUser.mdb;")

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Staff (ID, username, password) VALUES (@id, @username, @password)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 101)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Add")
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: Posting the exact error message that occurs when the insertion fails may be helpful to others.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Password is a reserved word and needs to be aliased or escaped. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/info

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to initialize the `connection` to the `cmd.Connection` property, change your below code to this one:

```
  cmd.Connection = connection
  con.Open()
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your `connection` while creating/executing the command. Use below code instead...

```
    Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=loginUser.mdb;")

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

        Try
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Staff (ID, username, password) VALUES (@id, @username, @password)",connection)
            connection.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 101)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Add")
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is you have not assign the declared connection to the command object

So you could modify existing command declaration to

`Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", connection )`

or

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
cmd.connecction = connection
```

I just revamped your code : see following

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Using OleDbConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=loginUser.mdb;")
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", OleDbConn)
            With cmd
                OleDbConn.Open()
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Staff (ID, username, password) VALUES (@id, @username, @password)"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 101)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "adfda")
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "dfsd")
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Add")
            End With
        End Using
```

You can use `Using` block to handle your connection ,The connection will  automatically close at the end of the using block